# How can we scale the marker image on zoom in and zoom out in android map

Tags: scaling, marker, android

I scaled the canvas but the actual marker is not scaled in the android map app. The following code is written in my code :

```
public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition position) {   
    float angle = position.bearing;
    float tilt = position.tilt;

    for (String key:canvases.keySet()) {
        Float angle2 = angle;           
        Float markerAngle = Float.parseFloat(markerDirection.get(key));

        if (angle==0){
            angle2 = markerAngle;
        }
        else{
            angle2 = (360 -angle) + markerAngle;
        }

        Bitmap x = canvases.get(key);
        Bitmap bmResult = Bitmap.createBitmap(x.getHeight(), x.getWidth(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas tempCanvas = new Canvas(bmResult);   
        tempCanvas.rotate(angle2 , x.getHeight(), x.getWidth());
        tempCanvas.drawBitmap(x, 0, 0, null);
        markers.get(key).setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bmResult));
    }
}
```